# How to cite a reference whose cite key contains '&' in the table

Tags: tables, bibtex, citing

I'm encountering a problem using TexShop (with Tex Live 2016 distribution) when try to cite a reference directly in a table. The cite key contains a '&', I guess LaTeX might treat it as a normal tabular separate mark, although it is in the '\citep{}' command. The code is like this:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{aastex6}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test for cite key contains `\&'. \label{tab:test}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Citation Failed     & {\citet{2007A&A...465..587S}} & Nothing appears\\
Citation Succeeded  & {\citet{2015MNRAS.453.1619A}} & A paper appears\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

I want to cite \citet{2007A&A...465..587S} in the table, 
whose cite key contains `\&', you can see the citation works 
here but not in the table. I didn't encounter this problem 
with CTeX in Windows, compiling the same script.

\bibstyle{aasjournal}
\bibliography{bbb.bib}

\end{document}
```

Typeset with LaTeX will give you the following error:

> ./aaa.tex:9: Missing \endcsname inserted.
>   to be read again
>                      \global
>   l.9 ...n Failed     & {\citet{2007A&A...465..587S}
>                                                     } & Nothing appears\
>   ?

Meanwhile, the .aux will get a wrong name for '2007A&A...465..587S':

```
\citation{2007A\global \advance \columncount by 1\relax \saveampersand A...465..587S}
```

which should be (if you cite this paper in other places of article, only if it's not in a table):

```
\citation{2007A&A...465..587S}
```

Using this incorrect .aux file, BibTeX will tell you:

> White space in argument---line 19 of file aaa.aux
>    : \citation{2007A\global
>    :                        \advance \columncount by 1\relax \saveampersand   A...465..587S}
>   I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

Finally, the citation won't appear in the .pdf file, as a contrast, the second paper cited in the table will appear, like this:

[image: pdf]

Yes, I can change the cite key by deleting '&' and then problem solved, **but I'm trying to figure out how to solve the problem without changing cite key, because the cite key is usually generated automatically by other tools, and it is not a easy task to change all the cite keys of such type.**

The 'bbb.bib' used in this example is:

```
@article{2007A&A...465..587S,
Adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
Adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007A%26A...465..587S},
Author = {{Shi}, J.~R. and {Gehren}, T. and {Zhang}, H.~W. and {Zeng}, J.~L. and {Zhao}, G.},
Doi = {10.1051/0004-6361:20066709},
Journal = {\aap},
Keywords = {line: formation, line: profile, stars: abundance, stars: late-type, galaxies: evolution},
Month = apr,
Pages = {587-591},
Title = {{Lithium abundances in metal-poor stars}},
Volume = 465,
Year = 2007,
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/0004-6361:20066709}}

@article{2015MNRAS.453.1619A,
Adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
Adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015MNRAS.453.1619A},
Archiveprefix = {arXiv},
Author = {{Alexeeva}, S.~A. and {Mashonkina}, L.~I.},
Doi = {10.1093/mnras/stv1668},
Eprint = {1507.05446},
Journal = {\mnras},
Keywords = {line: formation, Sun: abundances, stars: abundances, stars: late-type},
Month = oct,
Pages = {1619-1631},
Primaryclass = {astro-ph.SR},
Title = {{Carbon abundances of reference late-type stars from 1D analysis of atomic C I and molecular CH lines}},
Volume = 453,
Year = 2015,
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/mnras/stv1668}}
```

EDIT: Change all the pictures into source code. Posted the '.bib' file used in the code.
EDIT: According to the comments below, the problem might be caused by the `deluxtable` macro, so I changed `deluxtable` into `table` and tried again, same problem occurred.
EDIT: According to @DavidCarlisle, The problem is caused by `aastex6.cls` and/or `aasjournal.bst`. Add `\string` before `&` will solve the problem. You won't meet this problem using standard LaTeX template. Also, many people suggest simply do NOT use `&` in the cite keys, so that you won't meet the problem anywhere.

Comment: Welcome, some characters are just invalid within BibKeys. Sorry.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, I'm starting to think maybe it is just impossible.

Comment: Rather than posting screenshots it is better to code the actual code, and then highlight it using `{}`. This way people can copy and paste your code into their own documents and test it and try to fix your problem. It makes it much easier for people to hep you and hence m much more likely that some one will. This said, it is also better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) of compilable code and, in your case, a bibtex entry.

Comment: What automatic tools is this? I've never encountered one which would create a key with special symbols. Besides, changing them wouldn't be a problem. Just search and replace or a simple regex.

Comment: since you have provided no example this is untested, but I assume it would work if you used `\newcommand\zzzz{{\cite{2007A&A...465..587S}}` in the preamble, and then used `\zzzz` in the table.

Comment: if the cite works in normal text it would work in standard latex tables, so the problem must be with the deluxtable macros you are using (but just not using & in cite keys would be good advice)

Comment: I've had `&` in cite keys from journal-provided bibfiles, so someone thinks they're a good idea (or doesn't think).  But I never use those keys.  This is one of many reasons I don't use automated tools.  Underscores work fine for me (I have had to print cite keys exactly once but they worked then) so a script to replace all non-alphanumeric characters with underscore wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just for info, you forgot an extra `}` at the end of `\newcommand\zzzz{{\cite{2007A&A...465..587S}}}` but **it works!** I've tested it with a rebuild MWE.

Comment: @RunarTrollet These kind of keys are automatically generated by ADS http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv:1507.05446

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your advice, I have edited the question with source code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, David. Using newcommand or change the cite key will solve the problem, but I'm trying to avoid doing this, cause the there are plenty of citations with '&'.

Comment: @ChrisH Wise. But I have to work with other guys on the paper, so we usually don't change the citation keys.

Comment: @yayagua hmm well deluxtable/aastex  if you use standard \cite in standard tabular it works without error.

Comment: @samcarter that example didn't give "&" for me.

Comment: How about a script to copy the bib file, fix it and use that, with the fixed versions used in the .tex.

Comment: @ChrisH True, that was the only reference I saw in the question.  http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013A%26A...551A..26H is an example with &

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have provided no example I haven't tested this (but confirmed to work in comments above).

You can hide the `&` if you used

```
\newcommand\zzzz{{\cite{2007A&A...465..587S}}}
```

in the preamble, and then used `\zzzz` in the table

If the cite works in normal text it would work in standard latex tables, so the problem must be with the `deluxtable` macros you are using (but just not using `&` in cite keys, and sticking to simple `[:a-zA-Z0-9]` would be good advice)

---

---

Example added by CarLaTeX

EDIT: This is the MWE I used to test it (maybe does it works also with `deluxtable` macros?):

```
\documentclass[10pt,preprint]{aastex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand{\kH}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand\zzzz{{\cite{2007A&A...465..587S}}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable}{lll}
\tablecaption{blablabla. \label{tab:bla}}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Species} & \colhead{Model atom} & \colhead{A + \ion{H}{1}}
}
\startdata
\ion{Li}{1} & \zzzz & BB3\\
\ion{C}{1} & \citet{2015MNRAS.453.1619A} & \kH $^1$ = 0.3 \\
\enddata
\tablecomments{blablabla}
\end{deluxetable}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bbb.bib}

\end{document}
```

And this is the `bbb.bib` file:

```
@book{2007A&A...465..587S,
  author = {Author, A. and Perche Alsuno},
  year = {2007},
  title = {A duvenen propri vusa kel simbul la},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

@book{2015MNRAS.453.1619A,
  author = {Alexeeva, A. and Mashonkina, P.},
  year = {2015},
  title = {Keschi l e nurmal},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
```

I don't know how much this is similar to the original, I invented the `\kH` command and I don't know if the OP uses natbib or what else and with which style, however the result is this:

[image]

Comment: I agreed with that `deluxtable` macro may cause the problem at the beginning, so I tried just normal `table`, and same problem occurred. You can see the question was edited using the source code but not pictures, as you advised. This time I used `table`.

Comment: @yayagua your new aastex6 example runs without error if you do `{\citet{2007A\string&A...465..587S}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did what you said, here's the result:

1. Test with standard LaTeX, without `aastex6.cls` and `aasjournal.jst`: Yes, this worked. You are right, the problem might be caused by the template.

2. Add `\string` before `&`: Also worked with `aastex6` template. Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/manual/BibDeskHelp_2.html) you should not use & in a citation key:

> ... characters " "@',#}{~%" (including the space character) are never allowed, while you will be warned if you use one of "&$^" in a cite key. Cite keys are essentially TeX commands, so you should avoid using underscores, for instance, if you ever need to print the actual cite key itself.

EDIT: According to comments below, the quoted info is not 100% correct. I'll post a better if I find one.

Comment: What BibDesk says about `&` is simply wrong.

Comment: BibDesk doesn't say `&` is 100% forbidden, it says the user "will be warned".  And I guess it means that BibDesk will issue the warning. (Never used BibDesk, though...) So I guess & might cause problems and is not a safe character. Of course it would be better to tell when `&`can be used.

Comment: @Paapaa it's the deluxtable macros not bibdesk or bibtex that need to document that

Comment: There are a couple of other errors in that quote - you can't use numbers in TeX commands (of course you can give them as arguments) but you can in cite keys, and (at least with biblatex, quite possibly bibtex as well) you can print cite keys containing underscores.

Comment: Yes, you can use numbers in bibtex citekeys.